# Given known origin and destination latitude/longitude, how can I create its bounding box?

Tags: php, google-maps, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

Origin Latitude/longitude: 39.50000000,-84.78000000

Destination Latitude/longitude: 28.42000000,-81.31000000

How can I draw its bounding box?

The correct bounding box is:

```
+-----1
|   / |
|  /  |
| /   |
2-----+
```

I'm intrested to find 1 and 2 points.

I'm also attaching Image for better understanding the requirements.
[image]
I am writing code in PHP.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use  fitbounds

```
<body>
    .....
   <div id='your_map_id' style='height : 300px; width: 300px;'></div>
<body>

<style>

     var mapDiv = document.getElementById('your_map_id');
       var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(28.42000000, -84.780000);
     var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(39.50000000, -81.31000000);
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
</style>
```

Comment: What will be the 'your_map_id'?

Comment: your_map_id is the name of the div id that you use as container for the map .. each google maps need a <div id='your_map_id' style='height : 300px; width: 300px;'></div> for the right work . i have update the answer ..

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, I think your solution is working for me. I have a question I'm interested to know that why you shuffle the latitude/longitude as 

var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(28.42000000, -84.780000);
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(39.50000000, -81.31000000);

Also, I'm using 

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function() {
       // send the new bounds back to your server
       alert("map bounds{"+map.getBounds());
    });

to get bounding box coordinates.

Am I right in this? Please help me Thanks

Comment: The map.fitBound function require that you pass as parameter two var. first must contain southWest cood and the second must cibt northEast .. so you must check for you origin/destination lat/lng th ìe southern, northern, the easthern and the western and use the proper value for southWest/northEast var .. ..i hope this is what you are looking  ..and so if my answer is right please mark it as accepted